# Can Windows' copy command handle multiple files?

Tags: windows, command-line

On a Unix system, this command copies two files to a folder named `folder`:

```
cp foo bar folder
```

On Windows, this is not a valid command:

```
copy foo bar folder
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Can I do this in one command on Windows, using its built-in tools?

Comment: Perhaps this is a job best left to Powershell.

Comment: [Can I copy multiple named files on the Windows command line using a single "copy" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/922607/995714)

Comment: bash -c "cp ../../file1 ../file ."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
for %I in (file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt) do copy %I c:\somedir\
```

You can use this in either a batch file or directly from the command line.  Not as clean as *nix, but it works.

Comment: I confirm that it works.  Maybe if it was wrapped up into a batch file you could make it shorter?  So that I would only need to type `stevecopy foo bar [...] folder` and it would do that loop automatically.

Comment: I don't have to complete this 100% now, but for starters: for %%I in (%*) do copy %I c:\somedir\.  Powershell may be a better fit for something like this, but that is an additional install.

Comment: Been working on it for far too long and still can't get something to work.  Best I can do for you is the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  I posted my version based on your idea.

Comment: You will want to wrap your second %I in double quotes as a best-practice to handle spaces in the file name

Comment: Inside batch file you must use double percent sign, i.e. `%%I` instead of `%I` in both occurrences.

Comment: @steve.lippert check this please https://superuser.com/questions/1684553/in-windows-cmd-can-i-copy-several-files-with-the-same-path-to-another-path

Answer (score 12):

Windows includes **robocopy** built in, which copies multiple files from a single command:

```
robocopy a\source\folder a\dest\folder file1.docx file2.exe
```

Answer (score 7):

It's worth noting that if you have a wildcard expression rather than an explicit list of files then COPY does copy all the files to the target directory:

```
COPY srcdir\* destdir\
COPY *sy?.* anotherdestdir\
```

Anyone coming from a *nix background would find it particularly confusing that while works while explicit lists don't, because in Unix-like shells they're indistinguishable to a program – the shell expands any wildcards, so the program ends up with an explicit file list either way. This doesn't apply here because the Windows command shell passes wildcards directly through to programs and it's up to them to do expansion. (Also COPY is a built in command in the shell rather than an external program like cp on Linux, so in principle it could potentially disobey the usual rules about command line arguments, but that actually doesn't apply here.)

Comment: How does this help solve the problem? Can you create a wildcard for `foo|bar` ?

Comment: @Kevin You could use ??? if there are no other three character file names :-) The only DOS wildcard characters are * and ? so you're right, this isn't a general solution. But as the second half of my answer says, I was worried there might be people who *do* just want to use wildcards but get the wrong impression from the other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short batch script to facilitate copying multiple files:

```
set FOLDER=%1

shift

for %%i in (%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9) do copy %%i %FOLDER%
```

Usage:

```
my-copy <DEST-FOLDER> source [source2, source3, ...]
```

Comment: better: `for %%in (%*) do copy ...` and then the number of in files is not limited to 10 (still limited, but 255 is a bit more head room :).  Oh, and then you don't need `SHIFT` either. More: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: Not sure if I understand -- do you mean to have `copy %%i %1` ?  That could work, but it would try to copy the first argument on top of itself, which would just create a harmless error message.

Answer (score 2):

With the advent of [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about), you can now use the native Linux syntax:

```
cp foo bar folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
copy foo + bar folder
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted.  This gives me one file, named folder\foo, with the contents of both foo and bar in it.  I want to end up with folder\foo and folder\bar.

Comment: This concatenates the files foo and bar. Its *nix equivalent is `cat foo bar > folder`

Comment: You mean `cat foo bar > folder/foo`

Comment: Yup, looks like I was mistaken. If you have access to Powershell in your Windows environment, that might be looking into. Lots of the *nix commands carry over.

Comment: Good point!  I do have it.

Comment: Not exact answer for this question, but helped me! Thanks!